# how to print list in a isinstance (object,list)

Tags: python, list

i need help here. Could you explain me the value of list in the line-"if not isinstance(front, list):". I tried to find answer for it.i am new in python.

```
def sumtree(L):                         # Breadth-first, explicit queue
    tot = 0
    items = list(L)                     # Start with copy of top level
    print('items :',items)
    while items:
        front = items.pop(0)            # Fetch/delete front item
        print('Front:',front)
        print('list:',items)
        print(isinstance(front, list))
        if not isinstance(front, list):
            print('tot in if:',tot)
            tot += front                # Add numbers directly
            print('tot',tot)
        else:
            items.extend(front)         # <== Append all in nested list
            print('inside:',items)
    return tot


L = [1, [2, [3, 4], 5], 6, [7, 8]]      # Arbitrary nesting
```

Comment: @Psidom that edit did absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Psidom no, I never edited this post.

Comment: i edited the post :)

Comment: How do you call the `sumtree()` function? I suggest that you add this to your post. If it is already in your code, run it and look at the output. Do you understand exactly what is printed in each line when you run the program? If not, you should edit your question to include the output and ask about which lines you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your example input:

```
L = [1, [2, [3, 4], 5], 6, [7, 8]]
```

This is a list with 4 elements:

```
1
[2, [3, 4], 5]
6
[7, 8]
```

When you call `sumtree(L)`, the first value of `front` will be `1` which is not a list, so the `if` clause will execute. On the second iteration, `front` will get `[2, [3, 4], 5]` which is a list, so the `else` clause will execute. The `print()` statements in your code will show exactly what is happening. You should verify that what I have said so far is correct. You can follow the rest of the execution from there.